# Exact measurement of the memory consumption for std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I'm just wondering whether there is a way in C++11 to get an exact estimation of the occupied memory for std::map (in bytes). For example:

```
std::map<int,int> m;
```

assume "m" has 10 elements, I want to know what the overall memory consumption is. In some posts I see the following rough estimation for this particular case:

```
size_t map_size = sizeof(std::map<int,int>) + m.size()*(sizeof(int)*2);
```

However, it does not consider the memory overhead per element, is it somehow measurable?! Thanks.

Comment: "Exact estimation"? :) -- I don't see a better way than going into your standard library's header and seeing for yourself, but it's no cakewalk.

Comment: Assuming you mean at runtime, why do you care?  If you're so low on memory that the approximation of `map.size() * sizeof<thing>` isn't accurate enough, then you're probably in more trouble than you explained in your question.  Perhaps you could explain why you think it's important to have such an accurate estimation

Comment: Not mentioned in that dup link - you could put a custom allocator in your std::map template declaration and track the memory usage from there.

Comment: But even then, there is some system overhead in memory allocations.

Comment: I need it to compare the memory overhead for various std containers, I don't have any troubles in my programs, no worries. I'm just curious whether it is measurable.

Comment: I will try to use a custom allocator, sounds like a good idea.